# How to remove extra blank line below command line in vim?

Tags: macos, vim, macvim

I'm using vim 8.1.2292 on my MBP with macOS Catalina and this blank line under the command line really bothers me. How can I get rid of it?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the particular section of your screen so people understand what you mean?

Comment: I’ve added a link to the screenshot of the bottom left part of my vim screen. You see I’m asking about a line below the one with colon.

Comment: Maybe use a Dremel? =D    what is your `cmdheight` value? setting it to `2` would cause that appearance

Comment: @Piglet, cmdheight=1, setting it to bigger values raises the command line higher and higher. Excuse me, what's Dremel?

Comment: a rotary tool made for cutting metal and glass ;)  if cmdheight doesn't help I don't know. do you have any plugins that might influence or is this even the case with default settings

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it wasn't a problem of vim but my Terminal app settings. Some space left at the bottom of screen as I scaled up the font size (damned myopia). It's not even a full line.
Try scaling up or down a bit ('⌘' + '+'/'-') to get rid of it or at least make it smaller. Cheers!